# FASM - compacting "buffer db 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ..."

Tags: assembly, nasm, fasm

I was lucky enough to run into some NASM code that compiled fine in FASM changing just a single line;

```
buffer times 64 db 0
```

This works fine in NASM, but not in FASM - i had to write:

```
buffer db 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
```

There must be a more compact way to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably looking for:

```
buffer db 64 dup(0)
```

Answer (score 3):

In fasm you should write

```
buffer rb 64 ; reserve 64 bytes
```

Answer (score 3):

in fasm, when a label is folowed by a macro, its name should end with a colon

```
buffer: times 64 db 0
```

Comment: this answer provides the closest solution to the original code.